# SCEP Request on Mac

Tags: macos, keychain, certificate, active-directory

I am looking for a way to issue a SCEP request to my organizations CAIssuing server. I manage a number of Macs and we currently import the certificates by hand using a profile on a web server. I know that we can stand up an OS X server or Purchase an MDM solution but I would rather not do that at this juncture.

Is there any way to use a bash script or some other way of issuing a request for a certificate and having it import into the keychain?